# In Jekyll, do all variables have to be defined in _config.yml?

Tags: jekyll

In my Jekyll _config.yml file, I have:

```
...
test1: hello
...
```

And in my index.html file, I have

```
...
<h1>{{ site.test1 }}</h1>
...
```

When my site is built, in _site/index.html, I now have

```
...
<h1>hello</h1>
...
```

Here is what I want to do: in my _config.yml file:

```
...
test1: hello
@include _config2.yml ### this is not possible, but I'd like to do this!
...
```

Then, in _config2.yml:

```
...
test2: world
...
```

In index.html,

```
...
<h1>{{ site.test1 }}, {{ site.test2 }}</h1>
...
```

Which would generate, in _site/index.html:

When my site is built, in _site/index.html, I now have

```
...
<h1>hello, world</h1>
...
```

I'm trying to figure out how/if this can be done, the idea is that I have a one-page website with dozens of variables, and for the sake of my editors, I would like them to reside in separate .yml files.

Cheers,

Albert

Comment: In fairly new to Jekyll myself, but this seems like a perfect case for a data file. http://jekyllrb.com/docs/datafiles/

Comment: great! I posted as an answer also. Could you kindly mark it as the approved answer to help future visitors? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Jekyll provides the option to use data files usable in your pages and posts. This is a perfect case for them.

More information here: http://jekyllrb.com/docs/datafiles/